# Is there a way to restore ongoing gestures after a Navigator.of(context).push being called on Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to understand how to reactivate gestures for a Here SDK widget map after a Navigator.of(context).push method has been called:

- The root route has a Here Maps SDK map widget and all gestures work fine.
- In this root route, there is a button that calls `Navigator.of(context).push` to a new route with another map.
- The gestures work fine in this new page too.
- But if I `.pop` back to the previous root route, the first map does not respond to gestures anymore.
- The documentation says: ["Ongoing gestures within the current route are canceled when a new route is pushed."](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator/push.html)
- But how can I restore the gestures that were canceled for this route? Should I rebuild the root route after pop? I've tried `WillPopScope` without much success.

Comment: Try this ```Navigator.push<void>( context,MaterialPageRoute<void>(builder:(BuildContext context) => const MyPage(),), ).then((_){ // restore gesture });```

Comment: The problem was related to object destruction when the Navigator.pop is used;

Comment: To be more precise, the HERE SDK map object should only be disposed when the application is terminating. If not, all maps loses the ability to recognize gestures.